# Stacked flexbox vertical centering not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, height, flexbox

The following situation doesn't work in Google Chrome;

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div>
        <div>
           <h2>This is a test</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div>
        <div>
           <h2>This is a test</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
      <div>
        <div>
           <h2>This is a test</h2>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
body,html {
  height:100%;
  background:#1D1F20;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height:100%;
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-self: center;
    background:#87BEB7;
    padding:0 10px;
    &:nth-child(2) {
      background:#ADBEBC;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      background:#BE8A74;
    }
    > div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: flex-start;
      height:100%; // This seems to be the issue
      div {
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        align-self: center;
        background:#5C726F;
        padding:10px
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect the second flexbox-container (.flex-item > div) to be the full height of the flex-child (.flex-item) but it doesn't seem to work. (chrome only)

The workaround I have involves using position absolute, but i'd rather not use it.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwpzLX

Open in Firefox to see the desired result and in Chrome to see the current situation.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the working scss:

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height:100%;
    .flex-item {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        align-self: center;
        background:#87BEB7;
        padding:0 10px;
        display: flex;

        &:nth-child(2) {
            background:#ADBEBC;
        }
        &:nth-child(3) {
            background:#BE8A74;
        }
        > div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: flex-start;

            div {
                flex: 0 1 auto;
                align-self: center;
                background:#5C726F;
                padding:10px
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to set `display:flex;` to `.flex-item` and remove the `height: 100%`.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/omgL91r8/1/

Comment: Amazingly fast and correct! I wish I could give you an upvote.

Comment: I integrated it to my website and noticed that now everything will be by default vertical aligned to the middle. :(